# How to change the background color of the content when is long pressed and is showing the contextMenu?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, menu, contextmenu

[image]

This is just an example of how ChatGPT transitions from a clear background to a dark gray background for the content of the message when contextMenu is visible. Here are my codes:

```
 struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
        Text("Long press for menu")
            .background(.clear)
            .contextMenu {
                Button {
                    print("Pills selected")
                } label: {
                    Label("Pills", systemImage: "pills")
                }

                Button {
                    print("Heart selected")
                } label: {
                    Label("Heart rate", systemImage: "heart")
                }

                Button {
                    print("ECG selected")
                } label: {
                    Label("ECG", systemImage: "waveform.path.ecg")
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: What is your code doing/not doing? That gif seems like standard behavior

Answer (score 0):

### iOS 16.0+

You can provide your own `preview` to the `contextMenu` like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Long press for menu")
            .contextMenu {
                // Buttons
            } preview: {
                Text("Preview")
                    .background(Color.red)
            }

    }
}
```

For older iOS versions you need a custom implementation: Something like [this](https://medium.com/swiftui-made-easy/context-menu-with-preview-in-swiftui-242eab7b9375).